# cloud services payments

Tags: azure, amazon-web-services, payment

All cloud payments described in hours.

Let's look at situation when server spend 0.75s to generate page and only one time this month (because nobody requested website).

Here is text from AWS and Azure website

> "Pay only for what you use. There is no minimum fee. Estimate your
>   monthly bill using the AWS Simple Monthly Calculator."
>
> "Windows Azure Pricing No upfront costs. Pay only for what you use"

Does it mean that I will pay just for 0.75s or for entire month?

Comment: did you try contacting the customer support?

Comment: just think logically about this
why do I have to pay for a month of computer work?
let's pay something for keeping app in memory so it will respond faster but why for work of entire virtual machine that is not used.

Comment: You have to pay for the month because you have that VM at your disposal. You can run that VM flat-out for the entire month. If you don't, then that's up to you. It's just like renting a car, or a hotel room, or any number of similar things.

Answer (score 2):

You'll have to pay for one hour:

[AWS](http://aws.amazon.com/ec2/#pricing):

> Pricing is per instance-hour consumed for each instance, from the time
>   an instance is launched until it is terminated. **Each partial
>   instance-hour consumed will be billed as a full hour**.

[Azure](http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/):

> Compute hours are billed based on the number of clock hours your
>   service was deployed multiplied by the number of equivalent small
>   compute instances included in your deployment. **Partial compute
>   instance hours (prior to conversion) are billed as full compute hours
>   for each clock hour an instance is deployed**.

Comment: if it's really an one hour then clouds are definitely a best choice for hosting.  Maybe I don't understand correctly but looks like it's time from deployment to termination.  So basically prices for being in clouds not per using!!!  Am I right?

Comment: You'll pay for what you use. If you just need to use your web server for a hour or less (not really a real-life scenario), then cloud service is the way to go.

Comment: scenario:  my website is not popular and has only 100 pageviews in month.  I want to host website in cloud.  What do I pay in one month if page takes 1 hour to render and 1 hour hosts $0.10 ?

Comment: If you want your site to be available 24x7, then you'll pay 24*7*31*$0.10. Cloud services don't care what is it that you're running on your instance; as long as you have the instance running, you'll pay for each hour (or partial hour) it's in use. In your case, you should look into AWS Free usage tier - they'll let you use micro-instance for free for one year: http://aws.amazon.com/free/.

Comment: the word "use" is overloaded.  To you "use" means serving pages.  To cloud providers "use" means giving you a VM to use for your purposes. They charge based upon their definition

Comment: The lowest instance with worsts parameters costs in Azure $27/m.  %99.9 availability costs you a lot + it is slow!  For %99.99 of websites more important are speed and price.